# On the divisibility of the common difference of three Prime Numbers $> 3$ in an arithmetic progression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, arithmetic-progressions

Given three primes greater than three in in an arithmetic progression, how does one show that the common difference is always divisible by $3$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I did not do that. I will remember to include my attempts and thoughts  henceforth. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take that
$$p_2=p_1+d$$
$$p_3=p_1+2d$$
If $$d\equiv 1\mod 3$$  then $$p_1+2d\equiv 0 \mod 3$$ (since $p>3$)
If $$d\equiv 2\mod 3$$ then $$p_1+2d\equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why $d \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies p + 2d \equiv 0 \pmod 3$

Comment: For $p>3$ we have $$p\equiv 1,2\mod 3$$

Comment: ah! Thank you so much.